# sqlite query replace hidden/invisible carriage return with legitimate carriage return

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database with thousands of text entries. The text has many invisible/hidden carriage returns which shows the text in one long line. It displays okay on some programs, and on others it does not like this. If I just delete these hidden carriage returns and replace them by hitting the 'enter' button, everything works just fine. My question is how do I replace these hidden characters (which I believe are CHAR(13) or CHAR(10)) with a normal carriage return like I hit the enter button. What would the correct SQLite query be? I've found of examples about just replacing them all with an empty space but nothing about replacing with a normal paragraph.

Here is an example of what I mean:

-Result from growth in wool production in England- Enclosures were lands that were previously farms and they were turned into pastures for sheep- The serfs who had been working on the previous farm land were evicted

This is what I would like it to display:

- Result from growth in wool production in England
- Enclosures were lands that were previously farms and they were turned into pastures for sheep
- The serfs who had been working on the previous farm land were evictedd

I can do this by just going and deleting these hidden carriage returns and hitting the enter button. I could do this for the entire database, but it would take me about 3 months to do that.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Char's 13 and 10 are not hidden carriage returns.  They are valuable characters in your values.  Keep them in your database and deal with them in whatever application code you use to display them.

Comment: So, what happens when I just hit the 'enter' button in the sqlite editor? That takes care of the problem. I just need to replace those with that.

Comment: You need to find out what control characters are actually used. Run `SELECT hex(TheColumn) FROM TheTable WHERE ID = 42`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Normal" line break depends on application. Indeed, different OS use different line breaks.

I would, first, get sure to have all line breaks normalized in your database - I prefer a single `LF` (`x'0A'`), so I would ensure my data uses only this character:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET mycol=REPLACE(REPLACE(mycol, x'0D0A', x'0A'), x'0D', x'0A');
```

This would convert all `CR+LF` to `LF`, them all remaining `CR` to `LF` also.

Then convert output as desired for my application:

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable; -- LF, Unix like systems, ...
SELECT REPLACE(mycol, x'0A', x'0D0A'); -- CRLF, Windows systems, ...
SELECT REPLACE(mycol, x'0A', x'0D'); -- CR, Mac OS (ver<=9), ...
```